# Numpy: apply along axis returns error: Setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy

a very quick and simple error that I can't figure out to save my life:

```
temp = np.array([[5,0,3,5,6,0],
                 [2,2,1,3,0,0],
                 [5,3,4,5,3,4]])

def myfunc(x):
    return x[np.nonzero(x)]

np.apply_along_axis(myfunc, axis=1, arr=temp)
```

Expected output is the non-zero numbers of each ROW of my temp array:

```
[5,3,5,6],[2,2,1,3],[5,3,4,5,3,4]
```

However, I'm getting the error:ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

If I simply do it without apply_along_axis, it works:

```
# prints [5,3,5,6]
print temp[0][np.nonzero(temp[0])]
```

The weird thing is that, if I just add a np.mean() to the myfunc return to the first code block above, it works as expected:

```
# This works as expected    
temp = np.array([[5,0,3,5,6,0],
                 [2,2,1,3,0,0],
                 [5,3,4,5,3,4]])

def myfunc(x):
        return np.mean(x[np.nonzero(x)])

np.apply_along_axis(myfunc, axis=1, arr=temp)
```

I suspect it's something to do with how apply_along_axis work underneath the hood. Any tips will be appreciated!

Comment: Typically, you should post the entire Traceback with your question(s).  Does it occur when calling apply_along_axis?

Comment: Your `myfunc` doesn't return results of a consistent shape.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is just a convenient way of iterating over the 'other' axes.  In your case that is just 1 dimension, rows.  So even when it works (as with `np.mean`) it is not a miracle worker.  You can do just as well with plain iteration over rows, `[myfunc(row) for row in temp]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation -

> Returns:   apply_along_axis : ndarray The output array. The shape of
>   outarr is identical to the shape of arr, except along the axis
>   dimension, where the length of outarr is equal to the size of the
>   return value of func1d. If func1d returns a scalar outarr will have
>   one fewer dimensions than arr.

Because of the inconsistent shapes of the output at different iterations, it seems we are getting that error.

Now, to solve your problem, let me suggest a method with [`np.nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) on the entire array and then splitting the second output from it -

```
In [165]: temp = np.array([[5,0,3,5,6,0],
     ...:                  [2,2,1,3,0,0],
     ...:                  [5,3,4,5,3,4]])

In [166]: r,c = np.nonzero(temp)
     ...: idx = np.unique(r,return_index=1)[1]
     ...: out = np.split(c,idx[1:])
     ...: 

In [167]: out
Out[167]: [array([0, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])]
```

Comment: Thanks for the #protip!

Answer (score 1):

In numpy `1.13`, this definition should work:

```
def myfunc(x):
    res = np.empty((), dtype=object)
    res[()] = x[np.nonzero(x)]
    return res
```

By returning a 0d array containing the array, numpy will not try and stack the subarrays.